# Why is not the sum of bytes a byte type itself?

Tags: java, variables, types, type-conversion

```java
class Example{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           byte b1=10,b2=20,b3; //line 1
           b3=b1+b2;            //line 2
        }
}
```

Why there is a compile error in line 2?

```
Example.java:4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

Comment: No, it is not a byte: if neither operand is a `double`, `float` or `long`, the operands are converted to `int`

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly cast to byte, because the compiler *infere*s the sum of two bytes as a int.

Replace line 2 with:

```
b3 = (byte)(b1+b2);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is

```
class Example{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           byte b1=10,b2=20,b3; //line 1
           b3=b1+b2;            //line 2
        }
}
```

The cause of error at line 2 because JLS 5.6.2 makes it clear.

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using widening
>   conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary: If any of the
>   operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is
>   performed. Then:  If either operand is of type double, the other is
>   converted to double.  Otherwise, if either operand is of type float,
>   the other is converted to float.  Otherwise, if either operand is of
>   type long, the other is converted to long.  Otherwise, **both operands
>   are converted to type int.**

It means that Java prefers to treat smaller data types as ints, since any modern processor has at least 32-bit words anyway. A byte + a byte gets converted to an int + and int, and the result is an int. It's easy to add bits here - the new bits are all 0.

So you can solve this problem in two way - 


1. **Explicit Type Casting**

```
class Example{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           byte b1=10,b2=20,b3; //line 1
           b3= (byte)b1+b2;            //line 2
        }
}
```

2. **By declaring  final**

```
class Example{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           final byte x = 1;
           final byte y = 2;
           byte z = x + y;
        }
}
```